# Updating Info.plist in Swift code for AWS Cognito Identity Provider

Tags: swift, amazon-cognito, info.plist

I see the following error in my Xcode project console. Even though I have updated the `info.plist`, but it breaks the app every time, and is not working - any help/suggestion please?

Error in the console:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The service configuration is `nil`. You need to configure `Info.plist` before using this method.

This is the screenshot of my `info.plist` where I have added all the necessary entries:

[image]

Also, I am configuring AWS in my code as well, see below:

```
import SwiftUI
import AWSCore
import AWSS3
import AWSCognito
import AWSCognitoIdentityProvider

// Singleton CognitoService class
class CognitoService: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoggedIn: Bool = false  // Declare isLoggedIn variable
    var pool: AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool?  // Declare pool variable
    @Published var currentUser: String = "" // Add this line for user signin func


    static let shared = CognitoService()  // Singleton

    private init() {
        setupCognito()
    }

    private func setupCognito() {
        let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: nil)

        // for now it's okay, but later use AWS Secrete Manager to store these credentials
        let userPoolConfiguration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(
            clientId: "MY-APP-CLIENT-ID",
            clientSecret: "MY-APP-CLIENT-SECRETE",
            poolId: "MY-USER-POOL-ID" 
        )

        AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.register(with: serviceConfiguration, userPoolConfiguration: userPoolConfiguration, forKey: "UserPool")

        self.pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: "UserPool")  // Set pool variable
    }
}


@main
struct lunastars_club_4: App {
    @StateObject var cognitoService = CognitoService.shared
    @StateObject var sharedViewModel = SharedViewModel()

    init() {
        setupAWS()
        //_ = CognitoService.shared // Initialize CognitoService
    }

    func setupAWS() {
        let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:.USEast1,
           identityPoolId:"MY-IDENTITY-POOL-ID") 

        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.USEast1, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)

        AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
    }

    var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
                ZStack {
                    if cognitoService.isLoggedIn {
                        NebulaFunAppHomePage()
                    } else {
                        WelcomePage()
                    }
                }
                .environmentObject(cognitoService)
                .environmentObject(sharedViewModel) 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding cognito identity provider info in the info.plist, and updated my podfile. I am expecting that the app should not break after the info.plist is updated but it does break.